# How to update a key's value in an associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to update the the value for play_count in the array $games whenever someone goes to the games link.

```
$games[] = array(
"title" => 'Accurate Boy',
"link_name" => 'accurate-boy',
"id" => 2,
"desc" => 'Use a plunger-gun to help a boy recover a pirate ship toy from a series of sewers in this unique physics-based puzzle.',
"cat" => 'Puzzle',
"img_src" => 'img/accurate_boy.png',
"play_count" => 0
);
```

For example, if someone goes to the game "accurate boy", the play_count key gets 1 added to the previous value.

I can add one to the play_count key but it always resets after I leave the page.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving this array? (Database, plain text, etc)

Comment: I have a file called data.php . It is where the array is.

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark the it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone navigates to another page, say `other.php` and comes back, this array won't exist. You must persist it somehow.

For short term persistance (ie, user navigates between pages on your server), the `$_SESSION` array can be used, for example,

```
$_SESSION[$user_id] = $games_array;
```

And then, knowing the `user_id`, you can always retrieve that array and change values as needed from other scripts on the same application.

For real persistance you'll need a database of some sort.

Comment: If the array is stored in a file of its own called data.php could the array not persist in that file?

Comment: No. Unless you edit `data.php`, which is highly discouraged. Please take a look at databases. (Files work too, but it's slower and you might need to lock the file to prevent concurrent access to data.php)

Comment: Yes, data within PHP isn't saved automatically.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for clearing that up for me. Would using a database for just keeping the play_counts work out? Keep all the static data in the $games array?

Comment: there are an infinite number of ways to store data and arrange it. prescribed way is using an relation database and organizing your data in a normalized format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization